# NSDateFormatter DateFromString from RSS Feed returning (NULL)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad, nsdateformatter

I have allocated a date formatter, and I am trying to format a string which contains a date:

`formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

        [formatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];

     [formatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];

        NSString *date = [[stories objectAtIndex:storyIndex] objectForKey:@"date"];

        NSDate *formattedDate = [formatter dateFromString:date];

        NSLog(@"%@", formattedDate);`

As you can see I am 'NSLogging' the formattedDate to see if it had worked or not. Unfortunately it has not worked and therefore is returning (NULL).

Please could you tell me what I am doing wrong.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: NSLog the date string also.  What does it show?

Comment: One of the date strings shows: Fri, 10 Dec 2010 23:48:36 +0000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string "Fri, 10 Dec 2010 23:48:36 +0000" is not a "short style".

To parse that reliably, set the locale and an explicit date format:

```
formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSLocale *locale = [[[NSLocale alloc] 
    initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"] autorelease];
[formatter setLocale:locale];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"];
NSString *date = [[stories objectAtIndex:storyIndex] objectForKey:@"date"];
NSDate *formattedDate = [formatter dateFromString:date];
NSLog(@"%@", formattedDate);
```

**Edit:**
To then display the NSDate formattedDate in the format "Friday 10 December 2010", add this code after the above:

```
NSDateFormatter *displayFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[displayFormatter setLocale:locale];
[displayFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEEE dd MMMM yyyy"];
NSString *displayDate = [displayFormatter stringFromDate:formattedDate];
NSLog(@"displayDate = %@", displayDate);
[displayFormatter release];
```

For an explanation of the locale see [Apple QA1480](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa2010/qa1480.html).
For an explanation of the date format see [Unicode Date Format Patterns](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date_Format_Patterns).

Comment: Thanks for that, But it is still returning (NULL)

Comment: (Then why did you accept the answer?)  Anyway, replace the `NSString *date = ...` line with `NSString *date = @"Fri, 10 Dec 2010 23:48:36 +0000";`  Does it still return null?

Comment: No, It's returning: 2010-12-10 23:48:36 +0000

Comment: Ok, put back the original line and add this line after it: `NSLog(@"story date = {%@}", date);`.  What does it show?

Comment: story date = {Fri, 10 Dec 2010 23:48:36 +0000
  }

Comment: There seems to be some whitespace at the end which might be causing trouble.  Add this line after the `NSString *date = ...` and before the new NSLog line: `date = [date stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];`.

Comment: Thank you, that works perfectly, is it now possible for me to set the date as: Friday 10 December 2010

Comment: I updated the answer to show how to display the date in that format.  You may now accept the answer :)